# Android - How to check if a Print Service is enabled?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I don't know how to check if a Print Service is enabled or not. Is it possible? I tried, but I failed. It´s easy check if Location is enabled, but not to Print Service. Thank you for your help!

I need this information (Print Service is or not enabled) for to show the correct activity to users.

P.S.: Print Service was added in API level 19.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
PrintManager printManager =
         (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
if (printManager != null) {
    // print is enabled
} else {
    // print is disabled
}
```

Comment: I´m so sorry, but this answer didn't solved my problem. PrintManager is always different null.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_print_services");
```

Comment: Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_print_services");
This method returns null in Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Print helper has a method for this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper.html#systemSupportsPrint()

```
if(PrintHelper.systemSupportsPrint()) {
  //print service enabled
}
```